# The Same Origin Requirement of Reference Frames

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames

Currently learning special relativity:

My understanding is that Lorentz Transformations are the motions of Minkowski space that preserve the spacetime interval - and the same origin point.
That is two inertial reference frames must have the same origin for the rules of special relativity to apply...

But isn't this a really really unlikely scenario ?
e.g. take my reference frame at rest and my friend Ben's frame of reference at rest (relatively) who stands 5 metres to the right of me. Then, even in this very simple case with no relative velocities, we do not share the same origin point...

Obviously I've gone a bit wrong somewhere, but could someone please help me understand where ?

Comment: Note: [Homogeneous] Galilean transformations and Euclidean rotations also preserve the origin. Your concern isn’t restricted to special relativity.

Comment: In Special and Galilean Relativity and in Euclidean geometry, the “transformations” arise in two places: in the space[time] and in the tangent-spaces at each point [event]. In the tangent-spaces, the transformations must preserve the origin (the zero vector) in the tangent-space.

Answer (score 2):

> two inertial reference frames must have the same origin for the rules of special relativity to apply...

No, that's not true. Special relativity still applies, but the arithmetic gets a little messier if the frames don't share an origin: you need to use the full [Poincaré group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group) if you want to handle translations as well as boosts and rotations.

However, this is a non-issue. You and Ben can choose *any* event and call it your origin. And then you only need the Lorentz group for your calculations.

Comment: Ah i see. But how can me and Ben choose an event and agree on both its space and time components, when isn't the whole point of SR that me and Ben will not agree on both the location and time of any such event ?

Comment: @Daniele1234 You both agree that the origin event has coords (0, 0, 0, 0), but you don't agree on the coords of any other events (assuming your relative velocity is non-zero).

Answer (score 1):

Do not transform locations.  Transform **distances between locations**.  You and Ben will agree about the distance from the oak tree to the Eiffel Tower.   Likewise, transform not times, but **differences between times**, in case Ben, standing 5 meters to the right of you but in a different time zone, has set his watch differently than you have.  You will still agree on how long it will be between now and the commencement of the Easter parade.

Comment: That makes sense. But Lorentz transformations do preserve the origin right ? So, how does this factor into what you say...

Comment: If two events occur at the same place and time (so the spatial and temporal distances between them are both zero) then they are the same event , and all observers must agree on this.  So when we transform from my frame to yours, the origin remains the origin.

Comment: Don't forget that you are talking about an origin in space and in time, so although the spatial position of your frame's x=y=z=0 point moves relative to Ben's, their common origin (ie where their origins were at t=0) does not.